# Serialising text in C# the same way it's done in JS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

In Javascript you can do:

$form.serialize()

This will convert a lot of symbols e.g. "&" becomes "%26", "+" becomes "%2B"

How can you do that in C#/.NET? The only method I'm aware of that should do this is HtmlEntity.Entitize from HtmlAgilityPack, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

This is the same as what happens to the URL when you type it in a web browser e.g. https://www.google.com/?q=%2B

Googles for "+"

Comment: are you talking about encoding the URL or encoding the HTML?

Comment: All I want is a function that will convert any text into those symbols like the examples I gave. Yes, that does happen to the URL in any webbrowser

Comment: again, are you trying to encode ***URLs*** or are you trying to encode the content of a document? they are not encoded in the same manner.  Also, you state in the comments to another post that you are on mobile and you can't use System.Web, so I think you might want to make clear that you aren't looking for a C# solution, you are looking for a Mobile solution (when you say mobile and C#, I assume you mean .Net Micro Framework?)

Comment: hmm I didn't realise they are encoded in a different way. What I mean by mobile is Xamarin for Android, I'm not sure which .NET profile they are using.

Comment: xamarin uses the mono framework, and you probably want `Uri.EscapeDataString()` from the mono framework.  https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System/Uri.cs#L1797/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at:

```
System.Uri.EscapeDataString()
System.Uri.EscapeUriString()
```

In the case of "+" you should take first one.

Here is an example output:
[image: Sample Output using ScriptCS]

Answer (score 0):

HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode is one I have used.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot use that because I'm on mobile and System.Web is not available.